# ouput panel not rendering for picklist value onchange event

Tags: community, rerender, rendered, actionsupport, outputpanel

When i select the picklist Complaint_type__c value as 'others' then i need to rerender the output panel. I tried in different ways using Pageblocksections but no luck.

below is my code..

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <apex:form id="theform" >
            <apex:pageblock >
                <div>
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!ca.Complaint_type__c}" required="true" >
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="otherpanel" />
                    </apex:inputfield>
                </apex:actionRegion>
                </div>
                <div>
                <apex:outputPanel id="otherpanel">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="if({!ca.Complaint_type__c} == 'Others',TRUE,FALSE)">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!ca.Other_Type__c}" required="true" />
                    </apex:outputPanel> 
                </apex:outputPanel>
                </div>
            </apex:pageblock >
        </apex:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code fully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this `apex:inputfield` is required

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!ca.Other_Type__c}" required="true" />
```

So your rerender will work for first time but next time when you rerender it again it will not work unless you fill this required field.

You can use `apex:pagemessage` and `rerender` it to get same error message on the visualforce page.

So now best solution is make it required in controller and this issue will be solved. If you don't want to use that then you need to use `apex:actionRegion` or `Immediate="true"` to check if they help you in your use case.

Comment: Even first time also it's not rerendering.

Comment: @VijayKumar does first time `apex:inputfield` coming on page. Also you can change rendered condition as `rendered="{!ca.Complaint_type__c== 'Others'}"`

Comment: Thanks now i am getting inputfield first time after changing the rendered condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This,

```
<div class="container">
<div id="wrapper">
    <apex:form id="theform" >
        <apex:pageblock >
                <apex:inputfield value="{!ca.Complaint_type__c}" required="true" >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="otherpanel" />
                </apex:inputfield>
                <apex:outputPanel id="otherpanel" >
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!ca.Other_Type__c}" rendered="{!ca.Complaint_type__c == 'Others'}" required="true" />
                </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageblock >
    </apex:form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of code dumps you should also add what did you changed and how it will be helpful.

Comment: I had removed the [apex:outputpanel ] which has the id=otherpanel and Passed the id in the next line of outputpanel.
In output panel tag I had Removed the If condition and modified like this  rendered="{!ca.Complaint_type__c == 'Others'}".so when ever you choose value as others the output panel block will be rendered..
Hope This Helps!!!